# Compiler generated overloads for comparison operators

Tags: c#, comparison, operator-overloading

If there are operator overloads for `<`, `>` and `==`, shouldn't the compiler be able to create for `<=` and `>=` automatically?

```
 (a <= b) means (a < b || or a == b)
 (a >= b) means (a > b || or a == b)
```

At least, the compiler does the same for `+=` if `+` is overloaded.

Comment: you have to overload in pairs the relational ones like (< & >) and (<= & >=) and (==, !=).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+=` and `>=` are not the same from functional point of view.

`u+=2` is a short hand operand over `u=u+2`

`>=` is short hand for `> || ==`.

So you have 2 consecutive calls in second case `MoreThan() || Equal()`, which may provide problems like

- short circuits
- stack overflow
- return type of that functons may not be `bool` at all (as mantioned by @vcjones)
- ...

But in general: aggregate *automaticaly* (under the hood) user defined functions is never a good idea as a final result is not stable, as depends on concrete implementation, so unpredictable. And you don't want your compiler to generate unpredictable code.

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot. One reason being that operators don't have to return a bool (though I don't know why anyone would do this). For example:

```
    public static string operator <(Class1 a, Class1 b)
    {
        return "hello";
    }

    public static int operator >(Class1 a, Class1 b)
    {
        return "bye";
    }
```

This compiles fine, and in this scenario the compiler *can't* really make the other operator automatically. How should the compiler decide what the opposite value of a string is?

Comment: This is new. How is it supposed to be used if they can return another type other than `bool`? Any link for that?

Comment: One example where this operator doesn't return a boolean is Microsoft Solver Foundation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.solverfoundation.services.term.op_greaterthan%28v=vs.93%29.aspx